# NoClassDefFoundError in Apache POI/FileOutputStream

Tags: java, apache-poi

I get **NoClassDefFoundError** error when I try run below code. I checked tons of similar posts, but it didn't helped. What do I wrong? I think, there is something with FileOutputStream but I don't know what.

````
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Vienna");
        File viennaBatch = new File("C:\\Users\\majan\\Desktop\\CitiJanus\\Vienna.xls");
        viennaBatch.createNewFile();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("a");

        
        FileOutputStream fileOut
                = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\majan\\Desktop\\CitiJanus\\Vienna.xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
}```

error:

```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.RootProperty.setSize(RootProperty.java:59)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.DirectoryProperty.<init>(DirectoryProperty.java:52)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.RootProperty.<init>(RootProperty.java:31)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.PropertyTable.<init>(PropertyTable.java:58)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:99)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:121)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1357)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 8 more```
````

Comment: POI has several dependencies of its own. I suggest you use Maven to handle them. You don't need backslashes on Windows paths btw - make it easier on yourself and use `C:/foo/bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [the POI page](https://poi.apache.org/components/):

> Apache commons-math3 and commons-compress were added as a dependency
> in POI 4.0.0. Zaxxer SparseBitSet was added as a dependency in POI
> 4.1.2

The exception you're getting indicates that commons-math3 is missing in the classpath.